# Eloquent Javascript: Can't understand how the number value is determined in the sum function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how the **number** variable is determined based on example from the book *Eloquent Javascript*.

When I output **number** I can see it growing as the loop progresses, but i can't see where the number variable is actually set.

(Note: For anybody who understands Eloquent Javascript I have changed over the show() function to alert())

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}

function sum(numbers) {
  var total = 0;
  forEach(numbers, function (number) {
    total += number;
  });
  return total;
}
alert(sum([1, 10, 100, 1000]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
forEach(numbers, function (number) {
    total += number;
  });
```

In this part `number` is taken from the current `numbers`, and is equivalent to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  var number = numbers[i];

  function (number) {
    total += number;
  }
}
```

Comment: Still an extremely tricky problem for me. But it appears that you helped me understand this the most.

Answer (score 2):

It is set about half way down the code:

> `forEach(numbers, function (number) {`

Or rather, when that anonymous function is called:

> `action(array[i]);`

(Since the function has been passed as the `action` argument to the `forEach` function.

Comment: I know I might be sounded daft here, but I really can't see the connection at all.

Answer (score 1):

This one is obvious once you will know more the `forEach` method signature.

From your code

```
function sum(numbers) 
{   var total = 0;     
    forEach(numbers, function (number) {       
        total += number;     
    });     
return total;   
}   

alert(sum([1, 10, 100, 1000]));
```

then you need to know that the `ForEach` method takes two parameters :

1. the first one is the array to iterate on,
2. and the second one is the delegate to be raise against the current array item ... the function that will get called for every item of the array.

Meaning that the declared function with one parameter named number ( `function (number) { ... }` ) will be invoked for each items of the provided array `[1, 10, 100, 1000]`, and number will be set to each of those values.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, however, I've honestly spent over 30 minutes trying to understand your answer - I am quite new to javascript (it was why I started on Eloquent Javascript in the first place), so forgive me for my ignorance. But what I still don't see is how `number` is assigned a value in the first place, and then increments as the loop proceeds.