# Explain the anonymous function code example in Eloquent Javascript Chapter 6

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am having difficulties with the sum function that calls the anonymous function code example from [Eloquent Javascript (Chapter 6)](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html), while I understand what was clarified on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827477/eloquent-javascript-cant-understand-how-the-number-value-is-determined-in-the), I really don't understand how the anonymous function is called.

From what I understand this code:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}

function sum(numbers) {
  var total = 0;
  forEach(numbers, function (number) {
    total += number;
  });
  return total;
}
alert(sum([1, 10, 100, 1000]));
```

Is similar to this code (thanks to the assistance from @CKKiller in the other thread):

```
numbers = [1, 10, 100, 1000];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  var number = numbers[i];

  function (number) {
    total += number;
  }
}
alert(total);
```

But I can't run the second code example, what is wrong with it? From my understanding it is not possible to call the syntax **function (number) {}**, but isn't that what the first example is instructing the function to do?

Answer (score 3):

In the second code snippet, you're just declaring an anonymous function. *Call* it, and it should work fine. To "Immediately Invoke a Function Expression", you should do this:

```
(function (){
    // Your code
})();
```

Or

```
(function (){
    // Your code
}());
```

They're called IIFE's. (In quotes above)

As user1600680 pointed out in the comment below, to edit your code, you'll have to remove `number` from the parameter list. It would like like this:

```
(function () {
  total += number;
})();
```

Comment: Or if you're feeling brave, you can do `new function() { }`

Comment: Should be pointed out that either the `number` parameter shown in the question will need to be removed since it shadows the `number` variable, or the `number` will need to be passed as an argument to the IIFE.

Answer (score 2):

> But I can't run the second code example, what is wrong with it?

You have a **function declaration** without a name:

```
function (number) {
    total += number;
}
```

Function declarations **always** have to include the name of the function. See [section 13](http://es5.github.com/#x13) in the specification.

> From my understanding it is not possible to call the syntax `function (number) {}`, but isn't that what the first example is instructing the function to do?

Not it isn't. In the first example, you have a **function expression** because the function is defined in an expression context (it is passed as argument to an other function). Function expression don't need names. The expression is evaluated to a function object which is then passed as argument to `forEach`. `function (number) {}` does not call the function, it defines it.

> I really don't understand how the anonymous function is called

There is nothing special about it. The important aspect is that functions are first-class objects, i.e. they can be assigned to variables and passed to other functions  like any other value (primitive value or object).
`action` refers to a function, so you can call that function with `action()`. The function is passed directly to `forEach`:

```
forEach(numbers, function (number) {
    // ...
});
```

Although it is called inside `forEach`, it can update the value of `total` since it was *defined* in `sum` and therefore is a closure which has access to all the local variables inside `sum`.

You could have also defined the function beforehand:

```
function sum(numbers) {
    var total = 0;
    function add(number) {
       total += number;
    }
    forEach(numbers, add);
    return total;
}
```

But if you use a value only once, then there is not need to assign it to a variable first (or declare a function for that matter). For example, you also passed the array directly to `sum`:

```
sum([1, 10, 100, 1000])
```

instead of assigning it to a variable first:

```
var numbers = [1, 10, 100, 1000];
sum(numbers);
```

---

An equivalent to the first code that shows similar behaviour would be:

```
var numbers = [1, 10, 100, 1000],
    total = 0,
    action = function(number) { // variable assignment -> expression context
        total += number;
    };

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  var number = numbers[i];
  action(number);
}

alert(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd example does **NOT** call the anonymous function, it only declares the function. Therefore, the for loop does nothing to the `total` variable (I assume it's declared previously somewhere). The `alert(total)` will only output what was last assigned to total (since the anonymous function never gets called, `total` doesn't get updated).

Comment: The 2nd example doesn't declare the function. It is invalid syntax and the `alert` will never happen.

Comment: Well at least it runs in rhino, replacing `alert` with `print`, and declaring `total` somewhere before the code with an initial value (and `print` does output this initial value)